# DIV ordering in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've found some solutions here to reorder div columns in Bootstrap with push and pull, but is there any way to reorder the divs like this?

On bigger screens like desktop:
|A|
|B|
|C|

On mobil devices
|B|
|A|
|C|

Comment: Not in Bootstrap. Flexbox or jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly, you want it to be like this

desktop: (horizontal)

```
[a]-[b]-[c]
```

mobile: (vertical), b first

```
[b]
[a]
[c]
```

then you can use custom media queries for that, please check my fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/srp07Luq/

```css
.box{ background:red; padding:10px; border:#ddd solid 1px; color:#fff; }
.con2 .box{ background:green; }
.con3 .box{ background:blue; }

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .con1{ float:left; }
    .con2{ float:right; }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 con2"><div class="box">content 2</div></div> 
      <div class="col-sm-6 con1"><div class="box">content 1</div></div> 
    </div>        
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 con3"><div class="box">content 3</div></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no, I wanted to change the order of vertical divs.

Comment: then you can use this solution, doesnt require bootstrap http://tanalin.com/en/articles/css-block-order/

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the Responsive utilities within Bootstrap? You can use these utility classes for showing and hiding content by device via media query:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Perhaps you can leverage an ordering of these utility classes to get the desired effect?

Comment: Imagine my problem like that: I have a webshop. There is a div with price at the top (A), order info middle (B), and Buy now button below (C). I'd like to have the Buy now button next to price, so the order should be A, C, B in this case. I think I can not do tha with the Responsive utilities you've mentioned. Or am i? Thanks!